# How to add Jenkins plugins on docker container deployment?

Tags: docker, jenkins, plugins

I am running a docker container that contains Jenkins. The docker image I am using is the latest that docker provides.

The container runs and I can access the GUI when I deploy;

*docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name=jenkins-master jenkins/jenkins*

However. when I try to add plugins from the front end, there doesn't seem to be a list available. I need to have the pipeline plug in for my JenkinsFile.

Is there anyway to to declare the use of plugins when deploying the container?

I am working in an environment that does not have internet access so plugins would have to be added when the container is being built.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own image from a Dockerfile in Dev. Then I deployed it to the internet restricted environment.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
# if we want to install via apt
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ruby make
# drop back to the regular jenkins user - good practice
USER jenkins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt*
```

In the plugins.txt file I provided a list of plugins I would like to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this image this image contains all the necessary plug-in.

```
docker run --rm --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 adilm7177/jenkins-with-plug-in
```

You can check the description of this image. A list of plugin mention on the page.

[jenkins-with-plug-in](https://hub.docker.com/r/adilm7177/jenkins-with-plug-in/)

If you want to build your own image then try this

```
 docker cp jen:/var/jenkins_home/ ./jenkin_plugin
```

then create dockerfile, build it and it run so you don't need plugin every time.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:alpine
COPY jenkin_plugin /var/jenkins_home
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh" ]
```